# How can my Recorder record only from a specific window in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am making a Screen Recorder, the way it works is by getting screenshots and in the end it combines them in a .mp4 video. Now the program works by capturing the whole screen but I need it to let the user choose a window to capture instead of the whole Screen. For example if the user has opened paint and wants to capture this app, the user will press the "Select window" button and the program should appear there to capture.

Bellow is the whole programs script and Design for anyone that needs it to understand

**Form1.cs[Design]**

[image]

**Form1.cs**

```
 //folder variables
        string outputPath = "";
        bool folderSelected = false;
        string finalVidName = "FinalVideo.mp4";
        // Screen recorder object:
        ScreenRecorder screenRec = new ScreenRecorder(new Rectangle(), " ");
        public Timelapser()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }
        private void Timelapser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //items
            comboBox1.Items.Add("1x");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("2x");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("3x");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
        private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool containsMP4 = finalVidName.Contains(".mp4");
            if (folderSelected && containsMP4)
            {
                screenRec.setVideoName(finalVidName);
                timer1.Start();
            }
            else if(!folderSelected && containsMP4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must select an output Folder before recording","Error");
            }
            else if (folderSelected && !containsMP4)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You must select video name that ends in '.mp4'", "Error");
                finalVidName = "FinalVideo.mp4";
            }
        }

        private   void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            screenRec.Stop();
            Application.Restart();
        }
       
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            screenRec.RecordVideo();
            screenRec.RecordAudio();
            Timelabel.Text = screenRec.getElapsed();
        }



        private void SelectFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            folderBrowser.Description = "Select an Output Folder";
            if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                outputPath = @folderBrowser.SelectedPath;
                folderSelected = true;

                Rectangle bounds = Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
                screenRec = new ScreenRecorder(bounds,outputPath);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a folder");
            }
        }
      
        private void SelectWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
        private void videoView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                ScreenRecorder.v = 0;
            }
            else if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                ScreenRecorder.v = 5;
            }
            else if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                ScreenRecorder.v = 10;
            }

        }
```

**Recorder Script.cs**

```
 class ScreenRecorder
    {
        //Visio
        //originalee


        public static int v=0;
        //Video variables:
        private Rectangle bounds;
        private string outputPath = "";
        private string tempPath = "";
        private int fileCount = 1;
        private List<string> inputImageSequence = new List<string>();
        //File variables:
        private string audioName = "mic.wav";
        private string videoName = "video.mp4";
        private string finalName = "FinalVideo.mp4-";

        //Time variable:
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        //Audio variables:
        public static class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "mciSendStringA", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
            public static extern int record(string lpstrCommand, string lpstrReturnString, int uReturnLength, int hwndCallback);
        }

        //ScreenRecorder Object:
        public ScreenRecorder(Rectangle b, string outPath)
        {
            //Create temporary folder for screenshots:
            CreateTempFolder("tempScreenCaps");

            //Set variables:
            bounds = b;
            outputPath = outPath;
        }

        //Create temporary folder:
        private void CreateTempFolder(string name)
        {
            //Check if a C or D drive exists:
            if (Directory.Exists("D://"))
            {
                string pathName = $"D://{name}";
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName);
                tempPath = pathName;
            }
            else
            {
                string pathName = $"C://Documents//{name}";
                Directory.CreateDirectory(pathName);
                tempPath = pathName;
            }
        }

        //Change final video name:
        public void setVideoName(string name)
        {
                finalName = name;
        }

        //Delete all files and directory:
        private void DeletePath(string targetDir)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir);
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDir);

            //Delete each file:
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
                File.Delete(file);
            }

            //Delete the path:
            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                DeletePath(dir);
            }

            Directory.Delete(targetDir, false);
        }

        //Delete all files except the one specified:
        private void DeleteFilesExcept(string targetDir, string excDir)
        {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(targetDir);

            //Delete each file except specified:
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                if (file != excDir)
                {
                    File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
            }
        }

        //Clean up program on crash:
        public void cleanUp()
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(tempPath))
            {
                DeletePath(tempPath);
            }
        }

        //Return elapsed time:
        public string getElapsed()
        {
            return string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", watch.Elapsed.Hours, watch.Elapsed.Minutes, watch.Elapsed.Seconds);
        }
        //Record video:
        public void RecordVideo()
        {
            //Keep track of time:
            watch.Start();

            using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
            {
                
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                {

                    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
                }
                //Save screenshot:
                string name = tempPath + "//screenshot-" + fileCount + ".png";
                bitmap.Save(name, ImageFormat.Png);
                inputImageSequence.Add(name);
                fileCount++;
                //Dispose of bitmap:
                bitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }
        
     
        //Compare images
        public static List<bool> GetHash(Bitmap bmpSource)
        {

            List<bool> lResult = new List<bool>();
            //create new image with 16x16 pixel
            Bitmap bmpMin = new Bitmap(bmpSource, new System.Drawing.Size(128,128));
            for (int j = 0; j < bmpMin.Height; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < bmpMin.Width; i++)
                {
                    //reduce colors to true / false                
                    lResult.Add(bmpMin.GetPixel(i, j).GetBrightness() < 0.5f);
                }
            }
            return lResult;

            
        }
        //Record audio:
        public void RecordAudio()
        {
            NativeMethods.record("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
            NativeMethods.record("record recsound", "", 0, 0);
        }
       
        //Save audio file:
       private void SaveAudio()
        {
            string audioPath = "save recsound " + outputPath + "//" + audioName;
            NativeMethods.record(audioPath, "", 0, 0);
            NativeMethods.record("close recsound", "", 0, 0);
        }


        //Save video file:
        public void SaveVideo(int width, int height, int frameRate)
        {
            for(int k=1; k > fileCount; k++)
            {
                List<bool> iHash1 = GetHash(new Bitmap(tempPath + "//screenshot-" + k + ".png"));
                List<bool> iHash2 = GetHash(new Bitmap(tempPath + "//screenshot-" + (k + 1) + ".png"));
                //determine the number of equal pixel (x of256)
                long equalElements = iHash1.Zip(iHash2, (i, j) => i == j).Count(eq => eq);
                if (equalElements > 16380)
                {
                    var filePath = tempPath + "//screenshot-" + k + ".png";
                    File.Delete(filePath);
                }
            }

            using (VideoFileWriter vFWriter = new VideoFileWriter())
            {
                vFWriter.Open(outputPath + "//"+ videoName, width, height, frameRate, VideoCodec.MPEG4 );
                //Make each screenshot into a video frame:
                foreach (string imageLocation in inputImageSequence)
                {
                    Bitmap imageFrame = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageLocation) as Bitmap;
                    vFWriter.WriteVideoFrame(imageFrame);
                    imageFrame.Dispose();
                }

                //Close:
                vFWriter.Close();
            }
        }
        
        //Combine video and audio files:
        private void CombineVideoAndAudio(string video, string audio)
        {
            //FFMPEG command to combine video and audio:
            string args = $"/c ffmpeg -i \"{video}\" -i \"{audio}\" -shortest {finalName}";
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                WorkingDirectory = outputPath,
                Arguments = args
            };

            //Execute command:
            using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                exeProcess.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
       
        public void Stop()
        {
            //Stop watch:
            watch.Stop();

            //Video variables:
            int width = bounds.Width;
            int height = bounds.Height;
            int frameRate =v+10;

            
            //Save audio:
            SaveAudio();

            //Save video:
            SaveVideo(width, height, frameRate);

            //Combine audio and video files:
            CombineVideoAndAudio(videoName, audioName);

            //Delete the screenshots and temporary folder:
            DeletePath(tempPath);

            //Delete separated video and audio files:
            DeleteFilesExcept(outputPath, outputPath + "\\" + finalName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How should an answer look like to satisfy such a broad question? Short answer: the same way like any other screen capture software does it. Long answer: 1. Open Visual Studio, 2. Click on Open Project, 3. Open the context menu of your solution 4. Select "New class", ... 999. Click "Run"

Comment: @ThomasWeller that does not help at all.. As I said I need the "Select window" button to be able to let the user choose the window that it will record from, I will add now and the code for anyone that needs it.

Comment: I think Thomas's point is that this question is too broad for you to expect a good answer on Stack Overflow. There are several parts to your requirement: capturing a mouse click anywhere on the user's screen, determining which window is beneath that mouse click, determining the dimensions of a window, etc., etc.  Which specific part are you having a problem with? What have you tried, and what happens when you try it? Don't expect us to grok your entire app code, and write just as much (probably more) code to do your work for you.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I am almost sure that I need to get the handle from all open tabs and let the user choose one to Start recording from, but I am not sure how to do that. I know how to get the handle from all processes but I do not know how to record only from the selected handle

Comment: @KostasG: I'd recommend narrowing your question to just that problem, then. You could even possibly narrow it further. Are you expecting to literally record just from a specific handle, or just use the handle to determine the rectangle dimensions for your recorder? What if another window is obscuring part of the window you want to record? Try to break the problem down to the most specific question that you actually need answered right now. If you get that question answered and run into a separate problem, make a separate question for that one.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior okay thank you I will do just that!